# maximal ideals in $\mathbb{Z}_2[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am looking for maximal ideals in $\mathbb{Z}_2[X]$. I started by considering principal ideals.
\begin{eqnarray*}
\langle 0 \rangle &=& \{\}\\
\langle 1 \rangle &=& \mathbb{Z}_2[X] &=& \{0, 1\} \cup \{X, X+1\} \cup \{X^2, X^2+1, X^2+X, X^2+X+1\} \cup \dots\\
\langle x \rangle &=& x \cdot \mathbb{Z}_2[X] &=& \{0\} \cup \{X\} \cup \{X^2, X^2+X\} \cup \dots\\
\langle x+1 \rangle &=& (x+1) \cdot \mathbb{Z}_2[X] &=&  \{0\} \cup \{X+1\} \cup \{X^2+X, X^2+1\} \cup \dots&&
\end{eqnarray*}

Then I tried to combine these to get a maximal ideal, but I couldn't really see whether something like $\langle x, x+1 \rangle = x \cdot \mathbb{Z}_2[X] \cup (x+1) \cdot \mathbb{Z}_2[X]$ is already a maximal ideal or how much generators I have to add to get one.

Also, is there a better way to find all maximal ideals?

Comment: Note that $\langle 0\rangle=\{0\}$.

Comment: Note: $\left<x,x+1\right>=\mathbb Z_2[X]$, since we have $1=(x+1)-x\in\left<x,x+1\right>$.

Answer (score 2):

***Partial Answer:*** $\mathbb Z_2$ is a field. So the maximal ideals are corresponding to irreducible polynomials. For degrees 2 and 3, use the fact that a degree 2 or degree 3 polynomial is reducible if and only if it has a root in $\mathbb Z_2.$ As for finding *all* the maximal ideals, I don't know how to do it. Note that the ring $\mathbb Z_2[X]$ has infinitely many irreducible elements and hence infinitely many maximal ideals.

*Added:* The polynomial $x^{2^n} - x$ is separable for every $n \in \mathbb N.$  This will produce an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$ over $\mathbb Z_2$ as the corresponding splitting field will be of degree $n.$

Comment: Why do the maximal ideals in a field correspond to irreducible elements?

Comment: Not maximal ideals in a field. A field has only one maximal ideal, $(0).$ If $k$ is a field, then $k[X]$ is an Euclidean domain, and so every ideal is principal. Also an ideal is a prime ideal iff it is generated by an irreducible polynomial.

Comment: Ah ok and prime ideals are maximal. I still don't get why being a prime ideal is equivalent to being generated by an irreducible element, though. Is this only the case in unique factorization rings because there, the distinction between prime and irreducible essentially vansihes?

Comment: In general, prime elements and irreducible elements are not same. But in this case, the ring is an Euclidean domain, hence a PID, hence an UFD.

Comment: What about the ideal (x, x+1)? I can't find a single element which generates this. But we need to have one because we have a PID. Hmm

Comment: This ideal is actually the whole ring, since $1 = (x+1) - x.$

Comment: Ah, nice! This clears a big misconception I had. I think I basically get it now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

I would say that as $\mathbf{F}_2$ is a field, $\mathbf{F}_2 [X]$ is principal, so that each (maximal) ideal is generated by one element, which is irreducible if and only if the ideal is maximal, and then I will (try...) to find all irreducible polynomials in $\mathbf{F}_2 [X]$. You can look only for monic polynomials of course. Now, for a given degree $d$, could we find at least one irreducible polynomial of degree $d$ in $\mathbf{F}_2 [X]$ ? The answer is yes, and this is how Galois constructs finite fields : $\mathbf{F}_{2^d} := \mathbf{F}_2 [X] / (P)$ where $P$ is an irreducible polynomial of degree $d$ in $\mathbf{F}_2 [X]$ - he shows that $P$ exists. Now finding such a $P$ fast is highly non-trivial, see [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/0905.1642). Now, how to find all such - monic - $P$'s is another question...

Comment: I don't get yet the relationship between an irreducible generator and its ideal being maximal.

Comment: And ideal is prime if and only if the quotient ring is a domain. And maximal if and only if the quotient ring is a field. (Classic, google is your friend) You can define also what a prime (resp. irreducible) element is. (Classic again.) The two notions do not coincide. Now if your ring is a principal ring as $\mathbf{F}_2 [X]$, being prime or irreducible is the same. (As $\mathbf{F}_2 [X]$ is a UFD, but this is more generally true in GCD's)

Comment: My current understanding is this: in a PID, all irreducible elements are prime. So if I have an irreducible element, I can generate a prime ideal and I know that prime ideals are maximal. Correct?

Comment: Yes. You should a have look in a basic commutative algebra book covering all of this, as it is really classic. "Commutative algebra with a view towards algebraic geometry" for instance.

Comment: Thanks, I will check this out! I think I basically get it now but the concepts are still not very natural to me.

Comment: Then the book will suit perfectly to you, and remember, exercise ! ;-)